# how does the new keyword work if you dont give it a name?

Tags: java

I'm learning the Builder Pattern design pattern. I understand most of it but I'm just having confusion with the `new` keyword. [In this tutorial,](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm) in the MealBuilder class, he creates an object of type Meal, and then calls a method `addItem(...)` using that object. I don't understand what he passes in the parameter. I understand that the `new` keyword creates an instance (is instance another word for creating an object?) of a class but he didn't name it. E.g. I understanding the following:
`Meal mealobject = new Meal();` but I dont understand this: `new ChickenBurger();`

Comment: What is the problem with creating a new instance but not storing a reference to it in a variable(I mean, what exactly you don't understand about it)?

Comment: It simply creates a new instance and passes the reference to a method directly. You by no means have to assign this instance to a variable.

Comment: @user2040251 How would you be able to able call/get its methods and functions if you haven't given a name to it since there wouldn't be a way of calling.. if that makes sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should make it an answer. I don't know why is this being downvoted and wanted to close as _"unclear what you're asking"_.

Comment: @user3323950 You should extract the parts of the tutorial which you have troubles with an past it into your question.

Comment: Well there are many ways to get that object back. If there is an `addItem()` method, I suspect there is probably a `getItem()` method of some sorts, which you could use in a manner similar to the following: `Meal meal = mealBuilder.getItem();`. In this way you got that item back and you have a reference to it so you can call its methods.

Comment: `"but he didn't name it"` -- a key concept that Java newbies must come to grips with is distinguishing between an **object** and a **variable** (or object reference). One thing that you need to know is that **objects don't have names**. Variables can, but objects don't. For instance, if you create a variable foo, and assign it a `new Foo()` object, and then create a variable baz, and assign it the same object, `baz = foo;`, then what is the *name* of the object? foo? baz? Again, there is none since names are meaningless here. References are what matter most.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote

```
Meal meal = new Meal();
Item burger = new ChickenBurger();
meal.addItem(burger);
```

then this would behave the same way. However, if you aren't going to user the "burger" reference again, then there's no point in creating it. Just writing

```
Meal meal = new Meal();
meal.addItem(new ChickenBurger());
```

is simpler and makes it obvious to someone reading the code that the item is only being added to the collection (the meal).

Note that this isn't a hard rule. There may be some situations where you might decide that using a named reference for an expression will help clarify what the code is doing, particularly if it's not clear from the data types.